# Error deploying config to Solana network. Error: non-base58 character

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I'm testing how Metaplex's Candy Machine works and I'm having the tittle error while uploading using the CMv2-cli.

**My config file is the following:**

```json
{
  "price": 0,
  "number": 10,
  "gatekeeper": null,
  "solTreasuryAccount": "<8TBP4QrwkbDEmmYbA1EJum7HN8S2c1QYvEgTPdfb35Lh>",
  "splTokenAccount": null,
  "splToken": null,
  "goLiveDate": "27 May 2022 09:20:00 UTC",
  "endSettings": null,
  "whitelistMintSettings": null,
  "hiddenSettings": null,
  "storage": "arweave-sol",
  "ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
  "ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
  "nftStorageKey": null,
  "awsS3Bucket": null,
  "noRetainAuthority": false,
  "noMutable": false
}
```

**One of my assets file is the following:**

```json
{
  "name": "Test #0001",
  "symbol": "NB",
  "description": "Collection of 10 numbers on the Solana blockchain.",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 500,
  "image": "0.png",
  "attributes": [
      {"trait_type": "Layer-1", "value": "0"},
      {"trait_type": "Layer-2", "value": "0"}, 
      {"trait_type": "Layer-3", "value": "0"},
      {"trait_type": "Layer-4", "value": "1"}
  ],
  "properties": {
      "creators": [{"address": "8TBP4QrwkbDEmmYbA1EJum7HN8S2c1QYvEgTPdfb35Lh ", "share": 100}],
      "files": [{"uri": "0.png", "type": "image/png"}]
  },
  "collection": {"name": "numbers", "family": "numbers"}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 big errors in both files (config and the metadata).
For the config file you should not use the `< >` symbols, so your config file should look like this:

```json
{
  "price": 0,
  "number": 10,
  "gatekeeper": null,
  "solTreasuryAccount": "8TBP4QrwkbDEmmYbA1EJum7HN8S2c1QYvEgTPdfb35Lh",
  "splTokenAccount": null,
  "splToken": null,
  "goLiveDate": "27 May 2022 09:20:00 UTC",
  "endSettings": null,
  "whitelistMintSettings": null,
  "hiddenSettings": null,
  "storage": "arweave-sol",
  "ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
  "ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
  "nftStorageKey": null,
  "awsS3Bucket": null,
  "noRetainAuthority": false,
  "noMutable": false
}
```

For the asset file you have an extra space at the end of the creators array, so you should remove that extra space from this file and I assume from the rest of ur assets too. Should look like this:

```json
{
  "name": "Test #0001",
  "symbol": "NB",
  "description": "Collection of 10 numbers on the Solana blockchain.",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 500,
  "image": "0.png",
  "attributes": [
      {"trait_type": "Layer-1", "value": "0"},
      {"trait_type": "Layer-2", "value": "0"}, 
      {"trait_type": "Layer-3", "value": "0"},
      {"trait_type": "Layer-4", "value": "1"}
  ],
  "properties": {
      "creators": [{"address": "8TBP4QrwkbDEmmYbA1EJum7HN8S2c1QYvEgTPdfb35Lh", "share": 100}],
      "files": [{"uri": "0.png", "type": "image/png"}]
  },
  "collection": {"name": "numbers", "family": "numbers"}
}
```

Comment: I updated the config file and all the asset files and the error dissapear, thanks!